# What's the difference between X11 forwarding with `ssh -X hostname and xhost +hostname; ssh hostname`?

Tags: ssh, x11, xhost

In both the cases, I am able to connect to X11.

1. What's the difference?
2. And is xhost +hostname permanent, even after the base terminal is closed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `ssh -X`, you have a *tunnel* to the X server which is reasonably secure.  Using `xhost +`, you do not have that secure connection.

The `xhost +` command changes the X server properties so that other connections will succeed where they did not before (including after you disconnect from the hosts which you enabled).

Further reading:

- [Granting access to X server with xhost](http://possiblelossofprecision.net/?p=896)
- [xhost - server access control program for X](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36870/xhost-1.html)
- [X Security methods](https://www.ict.griffith.edu.au/anthony/info/X/security.txt)

Comment: Hi..thanks...now got it. And can you answer this too? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/265697/whats-the-difference-between-su-and-sux