# X11 authentication is not working in `sudo sux / sudo su`, but works in `sux / su.` Why?

Tags: x11, su, xauth

I have a vnc session and I can access X11 just by doing `su - user`, for other user, without the need of sux.

Also, when I am trying to switch to user, using `sudo sux - user` or `sudo su - user`, I can't access X11 and get the following error:

> X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.

But others are working: `sux` and `su`.

Of course, I am still confused about the message sux shows:

`Value of TERM has been set to "xauth -q remove localhost:100.0 2>/dev/null; xauth -q remove localhost/unix:100.0;"`

1. Why is it removing the old keys? What's the necessity?
2. And su and sux works almost same, both are removing old keys and both works. How and why?
3. And what's the reason for `sudo su` / `sudo sux` not working?

Comment: Ok, for my 2nd question, I can see from `xauth info` that it is using temporary authority file with only one entry of the required session's magic key, instead of using the default .Xauthority. But why?

Comment: you need to copy the cookies from the originating user to the target.  If you simply set `XAUTHORITY` in the target environment, you would likely not have read permission on the file (even as root, NFS-mounted home directories wouldn't work).

Answer (score 2):

The answer (for `sux`) is given in the script's comments.  It is transferring the X display-cookies from your original user permissions to root's, to allow it to open the X display using those transferred permissions.

Here's a section worth reading:

```
  # We highjack the TERM environment variable to transfer the cookies to the
  # other user. We do this so that they never appear on any command line, and
  # because TERM appears to be the only environment variable that is not
  # reset by su. Then, as long as 'echo' is a shell builtin, these cookies
  # will never appear as command line arguments which means noone will be
  # able to intercept them (assuming they were safe in the first place).
  sux_term="TERM='$TERM'"             
  # now we can store the script that will restore the cookies on the other
  # side of the su, in TERM!

  # Remove the old cookies. They may cause trouble if we transfer only one
  # cookie, e.g. an MIT cookie, and there's still a stale XDM cookie hanging
  # around.
  export TERM="xauth -q remove $DISPLAY 2>/dev/null;"
  if [ -n "$sux_unix_display" ]
  then     
    TERM="$TERM xauth -q remove $sux_unix_display;"
  fi
```